# grep for a pattern occuring 2 or 3 times

Tags: unix, grep

I am looking for regular expression which finds the occurrence like `696969` in `2345679696969`.

I don't want to search `696969` but to simplify it something like `69` occurring 3 times.

Something like this:

```
grep '[0-9]\{7\}69\{3\}'
```

but it searches for occurrence of `9` three times.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Group `69` with parentheses:

```
grep -E '(69){3}'
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "2345679696969" | grep -E '(69){3}'
2345679696969
```

All together:

```
$ echo "2345679696969" | grep -E '[0-9]{7}(69){3}'
2345679696969
```

or with a basic `grep` (thanks Avinash):

```
grep '[0-9]\{7\}\(69\)\{3\}'
```

Comment: I tried this before but it was giving below error:
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
I searched and got to know that it should use /usr/xpg4/bin/grep. Do i have to export it or what?

Comment: @vishalchoudhary see the updated answer. You can work with `grep` without `-E` option by escaping each one of the symbols: `grep '[0-9]\{7\}\(69\)\{3\}'`.

Comment: i tried it but it is not giving any output:
grep '[0-9]\{7\}\(69\)\{3\}' filename.
But when i ran it like this grep '[0-9]\{7\}696969' filename. I got the output.

Comment: @vishalchoudhary It is strange that `grep '[0-9]\{7\}696969' filename` works, whereas not the one I suggest. Does this work to you? `grep '[0-9]\{7\}\(69\)'`.

Comment: Yes this works fine and searches for single occurrence of 69 in the file.

Comment: @vishalchoudhary OK then the problem is in the `{3}` block. Try to test with and without `\`: `\(69\)\{3\}`, `\(69\){3}`.

Comment: I tried grep '[0-9]\{7\}(69)\{3\}' filename and grep '[0-9]\{7\}(69){3}' filename. Both doesn't works.

Comment: @vishalchoudhary you need to escape `()` around 69 like I indicate in my answer.